# Package color error

Tags: color, packages

Recently I went to try and compile my TeX document but I'm receiving an error that the color, which is 'RubineRed', is undefined despite that I am not using it for the entire document. Can someone see where is the problem where in the following document ?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP2}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[curve,frame,line,arrow,matrix]{xy}
%\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin5]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.35in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.35in}
\setstretch{1.0}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\topmargin=0.00cm
\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{111}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{xx}
\def\thenumber{xx}
\def\theyear{xx}

\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}
%\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newtheorem{exmp}{\rm Example}[section]
\DeclareMathOperator{\Jac}{Jac}

\begin{document}
```

And the error which I receive is :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode


Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(NSP2.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `NSP2',
               but the document class provides `NSP'.

Document Class: NSP 2012/01/01
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fleqn.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lastpage\lastpage.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))

! Package color Error: Undefined color `RubineRed'.

See the color package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.571 ...inecolor{abstractcolor}{named}{RubineRed}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please complete your code sniped, that it will be compilable. probably off-topic: you have load `xcolor` twice. try to the first add option `dvipsnames`, move it after `\usepackage{helvet,times}` and remove second one. also replace `\usepackage{psfig,graphics}` (note s on the end) with `\usepackage{graphicx}` (note x on the end). where we can find document class `NSP2`?

Comment: Where could we find the `NSP2` document class?

Comment: `\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000` really?

Comment: Also off-topic for the query at hand, but of general relevance: Since you're loading the `graphicx` package, there can be no valid reason for loading the package `graphics` as well. Moreover, you probably don't need to load `psfig` either.

Comment: I've downloaded this format from http://www.ntmsci.com/ntmsci/Contact and i'am trying to apply it on my own document.

Comment: You've posted the lengthy preamble, but you haven't actually posted the code itself that's generating the problem. It's very difficult to offer a diagnosis if the offending code isn't shown. (You've posted an error log, but that's not the same as posting the code that creates the error message.)

Comment: @Mico I've putted the link of the official document wich i downloaded and i'am trying to apply that journal on my own document; even when i compile the origin document it shows me the same error !

Comment: this is the link of the official document http://www.ntmsci.com/Areas/Conferences/FilesAndImages/162/NTMSCI_Latex_Template.rar

Comment: @Bernard i didnt use NSP2 in lmy current document i just integrated my own ducument in the official journal

Comment: @Zako i did what u suggest and it's the same, nothing happened also i didnt use NSP2 class in my document which i gaved the link of the official document

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}` *before* `\documentclass{NSP2}`.

Comment: If you study the log, you'll be able to see that the error occurs while reading `NSP2.cls` -- the parentheses indicates what happens while reading a specific file, and the paren before `NSP2.cls` hasn't been closed. And indeed, if you look in the file you'll see that `RubineRed` is used, but  that `dvipsnames` is not passed to the `color` package, which is needed for that colour to be defined. Hence, the class itself is buggy. @esdd's suggestion, or alternatively using `\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames]{NSP}`, both work though.

Comment: Well, Thanks alots for your help but when i do what @esdd said about passing the option to package it shows no error and its compile fine but the problem is with the pdf document, there is no color to see; there is no RubineRed color to see in the pdf file which i want to put it !

Comment: Then use the suggestion of @TorbjørnT. `\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames]{NSP}`.

Comment: What exactly do you expect, and what do you get? Showing a screenshot of the PDF might be useful. That colour is used just one place in the class file, and that is to define the background colour of the box in which the journal title is placed (on the first page, right above the title of the paper).

Comment: Yes it works fine now, thenk you all for your help, thank you esdd and @Turbjorn T.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a document using `NSP2.cls` with

```
latex filename
dvips filename
ps2pdf filename
```

it will work fine, as the `RubineRed` colour is one of the colours defined by the  `dvips` driver. If you want to compile with

```
pdflatex filename
```

instead, then you need to pass the `dvipsnames` to the `color` package, with either

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP2}
```

or

```
\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames]{NSP2}
```

The only part in the document using that colour is the box containing the journal name, located at the top of the first page, above the title of the article. Where it says "New Trends in Mathematical Sciences" in this screenshot:

[image: first page of sample document]